How does the dot product distribute/associate over the outer product?
I'm interested in the quantity $\nabla\times(\mathbf{A}\times(c\mathbf{B}))$, where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are vectors and $c$ is a scalar. Also, $\mathbf{A}$ is a constant vector.
The cross product rule gives
$$\nabla\times(\mathbf{A}\times(c\mathbf{B})) = \textbf{A}(\nabla\cdot(c\mathbf{B})) - c\mathbf{B}(\nabla\cdot\textbf{A}) + (c\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\textbf{A} - (\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)(c\mathbf{B}) = \textbf{A}(\nabla\cdot(c\mathbf{B})) - (\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)(c\mathbf{B})$$
since $\mathbf{A}$ is constant.
I'm happy with the first term, I can expand $\nabla\cdot(c\mathbf{B})$ to get
$$\textbf{A}(\nabla\cdot(c\mathbf{B})) = \textbf{A}(c\nabla\cdot\textbf{B} + \textbf{B}\cdot\nabla c).$$
For the second term, since $(\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}=\textbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B})$, it can be written as $\textbf{A}\cdot(\nabla(c\mathbf{B}))$, in which $\nabla(c\mathbf{B})$ can be expanded:
$$(\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla)(c\mathbf{B}) = \textbf{A}\cdot(\nabla(c\mathbf{B})) = \textbf{A}\cdot(\nabla c\otimes\mathbf{B} + c\nabla\mathbf{B}).$$
In this equation I'm happy with the second term, which is just $c\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{B}$, however the first term is causing me trouble; what is $\textbf{A}\cdot(\nabla c\otimes\mathbf{B})$?
In short - how does the dot product distribute/associate over the outer product?

It doesn't "distribute". There are two definitions you could take: $$A\cdot(B\otimes C) = (A\cdot B)C$$ or $$A\cdot(B\otimes C) = (A\cdot C)B.$$ It appears you are using the former.
It's not clear at all what your goal here is though, as throughout all your calculations it looks like you are applying some simplification and immediately undoing it.
